# How to download BERT model locally, without use of package?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Company firewall seems to prevent me from just using

```
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens")
```

so I need to download this model locally and then read it into Python.
Couldn't find the direct AWS link, seems to be typically in this form: but did not work

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens-pytorch_model.bin
```

Tried these similar questions/solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62317931/how-to-predownload-a-transformers-model/64280935#64280935) but did not work, since I can't run the first line to download from pretrained in Python, I need an external solution

Comment: [here](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens/tree/main)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, for example:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, TFAutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')
bert=TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')

tokenizer.save_pretrained("./models/tokenizer/")
bert.save_pretrained("./models/bert/")
```

Answer (score 1):

If some model is used, there is the .cache folder which you can copy/paste to where you want, and use it in SentenceTransformer(path/to/your/folder/with/model)
I am using Linux, so the .cache folder is in /home/username/.cache/torch/sentence-transformers.